# How to detect which part of the video is using copyright audio on facebook

Tags: video, audio, copyright

I am having a issue i.e: Facebook deletes the video uploaded by me and says It contains copyright audio. It is `6min` video so **how could I know which part is being aborted by Facebook**.

Thanks a million.

Comment: Are you using any copyrighted songs in your video?  This could be something as simple as playing in the background of a clip.

Comment: Not sure about Facebook, but I know that with youtube, there is an appeals process for when their algorithms detect copyrighted music when none exists.  Which leads me to the question; is Facebook actually hosting the video?  Because if so, you could just try a different host.

Comment: What @JasonConrad said is probably going to be your best solution. Facebook support is pretty much non-existant for things like this. Most of the algorithms are getting better but facebooks is probably the weakest still